# bpy object dimensions in Python script does not match the actual dimensions

Tags: python, dimensions

I am currently writing a Python script using bpy and running it on Blender 3.1.2. I have imported an object of type CURVE from another .blend file and I need to find its dimensions in the current script.

If I directly run `bpy.context.object.dimensions` in the Python console, I get the correct dimensions. I verified this by using the Measure tool and also in the object properties.

[image]

[image]

However, when I run this exact same line of code from my Python script, the dimensions are incorrect. I have ensured that the correct object is selected, yet the dimensions do not match.

[image]

Why could this be happening? Any help is appreciated.

**Update (Added code snippet)**

```py
def import_collection_from_file(filepath: str, collection_matcher: str):
    # Copy collection from file
    with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath) as (data_from, data_to):
        data_to.collections = [coll for coll in data_from.collections if collection_matcher in coll]
    
    # Add collection to current scene
    for coll in data_to.collections:
        bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(coll)
    return data_to.collections

def get_objects_from_collection(collection: bpy.types.Collection, object_matcher: str, direct_children_only: bool = True):
    objects = []
    children = list(collection.objects) if direct_children_only else list(collection.all_objects)
    for object in children:
        if object_matcher in object.name:
            objects.append(object)
    return objects



filepath = '' # path to file to import the collection from

# Import the first collection which contains 'Profile' in its name
collection = import_collection_from_file(filepath, 'Profile')[0]

# Access the first object in the collection which contains 'Profile' in its name
obj = get_objects_from_collection(collection, 'Profile')[0]

# Select the currently added object
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
obj.select_set(True)


print('selected objects:', bpy.context.selected_objects[:]) # prints only the object that is currently imported

print('context.object dimensions:', bpy.context.object.dimensions)

profile = bpy.data.objects['Profile']
print('profile.dimensions:', profile.dimensions)
print('selected_objects dimensions:', bpy.context.selected_objects[0].dimensions)
```

Comment: Hello, it would be immensely more easier to help you if you shared the part of the script that outputs these values. Thanks :)

Comment: +1 to posting the code, Also you should change your units in the viewport to metric instead of inches, and compare those values the python Vector units are in metric, pretty sure and that will simplify sorting it out a bit.

Comment: @Gorgious, I have added the code snippet for your reference.

Comment: @Jakemoyo Yeah I took the unit conversion into account. The dimensions in the viewport are in inches and are the same as the first screenshot when converted to meters (i.e (1.52, 1.87, 0.0)). The values in the third screenshot (the output of the script) are also in meters but are **not** equivalent to (60.2, 73.8, 0.0) inches.

Comment: your object has any modifiers?

Comment: Also are you sure the scale is applied in the source object .blend file? have you tested this issue with a pair of 100% clean blend files? Like with the source file containing only a brand new default curve added into a collection

Comment: @XY No I have not added any modifiers

Comment: @Jakemoyo Yes, the scale and dimensions in the source file are correct. I just created a new source file containing only this curve and the issue still persists. One surprising observation is that if I run the script multiple times inside the target .blend file, the dimensions are incorrect only for the first time. After that, the values are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution to the problem. As I am importing the curve from another file, it requires an update for the objects that are modified by the script.

Adding `bpy.context.view_layer.update()` after importing the object updates the view layer and the dimensions are now correct.

**Final Code:**

```py
# Functions here

filepath = '' # path to file to import the collection from

# Import the first collection which contains 'Profile' in its name
collection = import_collection_from_file(filepath, 'Profile')[0]

# Access the first object in the collection which contains 'Profile' in its name
obj = get_objects_from_collection(collection, 'Profile')[0]

# Select the currently added object
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
obj.select_set(True)

# Update the view layer
bpy.context.view_layer.update()

# .dimensions now gives correct results
```